# Critical exponents in cosmological phase transitions: existing and useful?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, computational-physics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

I'm working on phase transitions in the early universe. Generally, a particle physics model in form of a Lagrangian is taken, the one-loop corrections in the potential for zero and finite temperature are added and then one searces for the existence of different phases with individual vacua in the model for different parameter sets (masses and couplings, usually), e.g. by using the CosmoTransitions python package.

Yesterday I had the vague idea to speed up the code by findig classes of phase transitions (within one given model) which can be described by critical exponents, just as in condensed matter physics. I was guessing that the temperature dependence of the vacuum expectation value could be described by some function similar to

$\frac{\Delta \phi}{T} \propto \left(1 - \frac{T}{T_c}\right)^\alpha$

such that $\frac{\Delta \phi}{T}$ can be taken as an order parameter and $\alpha$ as a critical exponent, connected to some underlying RGEs of the system.

However, I cannot find anything concerning that issue in the literature. Does one of you have a guess of how to make sense of this idea or possibly even some valuable references?

Thanks!

Comment: why not also try https://www.physicsoverflow.org/ which is only theoretical

Comment: I guess, I'll have to try that